# Let $A\subset [-\pi, \pi]$ be a measurable set. Show that $\lim_{k\to \infty}\int_A \cos(kt) \text{d}t=0. $

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

This is a homework problem, however I don't know how to start with. Let $A\subset [-\pi, \pi]$ be a measurable set. Show that $$\lim_{k\to \infty}\int_A \cos(kt) \text{d}t=0. $$ I was thinking theorems like dominated convergence theorem etc. but don't know how to apply them. I read somewhere that this can be shown with Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, but we haven't proved that in class. What we recently proved was that the functions $\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{ikt}:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ form a Hilbert basis in the space of square-integrable $2\pi$-periodic functions $L^2_{2\pi, \mathbb{C}}([-\pi, \pi])$. Any hints or help is appreciated.

Comment: Then you know that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\pm\infty}\int \chi_A e^{ikt}dt=0$, where $\chi_{A}$ is the indicator function of the set $A$.

Comment: **Hint:** Bessel's inequality.

Comment: Is this right: $\int_A \cos(kt)=\int_{[-\pi, \pi]}\chi_A \cos(kt)=\langle \chi_A, \cos(kt) \rangle$ and for given $\epsilon>0$ it must be $|\langle \chi_A, \cos(kt)\rangle|\geq \epsilon$ for only finite number of $k$'s, because otherwise Bessel's inequality would give $\lVert \chi_A\rVert^2\geq\infty$ which can't be true since $\lVert \chi_A\rVert^2=2\pi$ ?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Great, thanks for the hint, it really helped!

Comment: @Infinitebig feel free to write your comment as an answer and accept it btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the (detailed) solution to the question. The integral can be written as $$\int_A\cos(kt)\text{d}t=\sqrt{\pi}\int_{[-\pi, \pi]}\chi_A\frac{\cos(kt)}{\sqrt{\pi}}\text{d}t=\sqrt{\pi}\Big\langle\chi_A, \frac{\cos(kt)}{\sqrt{\pi}}\Big\rangle. $$ Let's recap the Bessel's inequality $$\sum_{e\in E}|\langle x, e\rangle|^2\leq \lVert x\rVert^2$$ for any orthonormal set $E$. We know that the set $$\Big\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cos(kt):k\in\mathbb{N}\Big\}\cup\Big\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sin(kt):k\in\mathbb{N}\Big\}\cup\Big\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\Big\}$$ is an orthonormal set in $L^2_{\mathbb{R}}([-\pi, \pi])$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Then $$\Big|\Big\langle \chi_A, \frac{\cos(kt)}{\sqrt{\pi}}\Big\rangle\Big|\geq\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$ for only finite number of $k$'s, because otherwise Bessel's inequality would give $\lVert\chi_A\rVert^2=\infty$. Therefore there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $$\Big|\Big\langle \chi_A, \frac{\cos(kt)}{\sqrt{\pi}}\Big\rangle\Big|<\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\pi}} \quad \forall k\geq N.$$ Thus we have $$\Big|\int_A\cos(kt)\text{d}t\Big|=\sqrt{\pi}\Big|\Big\langle \chi_A, \frac{\cos(kt)}{\sqrt{\pi}}\Big\rangle\Big|<\epsilon \quad \forall k\geq N $$ i.e. $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_A\cos(kt)\text{d}t=0. $$

Comment: Think you could also show that an orthonormal sequence converges weakly to 0, then show that $\cos(nt)$ is orthonormal in $L^2$.

Comment: @Seh-kai Yes, that is pretty short proof, although it uses the same theorem, Bessel's inequality namely.